# Wiimote disconnects everytime

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii, wiimote

Ok so I started my Wii and I noticed that the Wiimote loses connections with the console, specially when it lands on icons, buttons and that.
I though that could be the batteries or the sensor bar, but everything seems to be fine.
Anyone else got this problem? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Decent question, but maybe (unless that's all there really is) add more details, just in case

Comment: When you say "loses connections", do you mean outright disconnects (lights turn off, buttons don't do anything)? Or do you mean the pointer on the screen vanishes?

Answer (score 2):

## If "loses connections" means "the pointer vanishes"...

#### ...TL;DR, it could be the sensor in the top of your Wiimote malfunctioning.

The way a Wiimote works is actually the opposite of how you would expect it to. Contrary to its name, the Sensor Bar doesn't actually do the sensing. The Sensor Bar is an array of LED lights powered by the Wii -- though it seems unclear [if they're infrared](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-Nintendo-Wii-s-sensor-bar-work#:%7E:text=The%20two%20ends%20of%20the,orientation%20of%20its%20internal%20gyroscopes.), or [if they're just plain LEDs](https://www.zedlabz.com/blogs/news/what-is-in-a-wii-sensor-bar-and-how-does-it-work).

It's the Wiimote, via Bluetooth, that does all the heavy lifting. The Wiimote picks up the lights from the Sensor Bar, transmits gyroscope and so forth information via Bluetooth, and handles the logistics of it itself.

That said, if you're having problems with the Wiimote's pointing, that's usually due to interference between the Wiimote and a viable light source -- note I didn't say the Sensor Bar, because people have proven that even just two tea-light candles work just as well as the bar. Make sure the Wiimote has a clear view of the Sensor Bar, that the Sensor Bar's LEDs aren't broken, and that it's properly plugged in. If all of the above is okay, the Wiimote's sensor itself may be broken.

## If it means "disconnects", lights off and all...

#### ...TL;DR, the Wiimote's main board could have come disconnected from the battery housing, or the housing's contacts are bad.

A big problem I've found with my older Wiimotes is that, due to the amount of shaking, movement, bumps and nicks, and so on and so forth, is the board has a tendency to snap off of the battery housing, or the battery's contacts can wear away, or (in the worst cases), the batteries themselves can corrode. If you've ever smacked a Wiimote to get it working, and it does, that may be the case.

If it's the board snapped or broke, it's fairly simple to tell; the Wiimote shouldn't rattle when shaken. If it isn't, open the battery compartment and check to make sure that the batteries (and the housing's contacts) aren't corroded. You can also check the elasticity of the springs in the contacts to make sure that the batteries are actually making contact properly, and that they don't lose connection when tilted because the spring is loose.

## Unfortunately, these all usually mean buy a new Wiimote, or learn to self-repair them.

With the exception to very mild battery corrosion, since it's possible to simply clean the corrosion out, most of these instances mean the Wiimote is busted, and will need repairing. Nintendo ***has stopped accepting repairs on Wii systems and Wiimotes in 2020,*** which unfortunately means any repairs that you do need done must be done either manually or by a local tech shop that accepts Wiimotes.

Otherwise, it may be time to simply replace your Wiimote. The most expensive I've seen them get third-party is about $60, but [Nintendo sells them themselves for about $40](https://www.nintendo.com/us/store/products/wii-remote-plus-yoshi-102150).